# I can't add custom css file

Tags: magento2.4

[image]

I created the default_head_blocks.xml file in app/design/frontend/Magento_Theme/luma/layout and the local-m.css file in app/design/frontend/web/css/
and the code for the xml is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set your Magento application to the **developer mode** for this testing.
2. Add the following folders to your custom theme

   - app / design / frontend / **[vendor] / [theme]** / Magento_Theme / layout
   - app / design / frontend / **[vendor] / [theme]** / web / css
3. Create the following files:

   - app / design / frontend / **[vendor] / [theme]** / Magento_Theme / layout / default_head_blocks.xml
   - app / design / frontend / **[vendor] / [theme]** / web / css / local-m.css
4. place this code within **default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/local-m.css" />
    <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

5. After that please run the below command:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:static-content:deploy -f 
php bin/magento c:f
```